# MySQL 5.7 referencing error

Tags: mysql, reference

I have two tables `department` and `employee`. I want to reference `department` in `employee` using MySQL. Here are my codes below and the error message:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO int (4) NOT NULL,
    -> DNAME CHAR (15), DFLOOR int(1),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMPNO int (4) NOT NULL,
    -> ENAME CHAR (10),
    -> MGR CHAR (9),
    -> DEPTNO int (4) NOT NULL,
    -> SAL float(7,2),
    -> JOB_STATUS float(7,2),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO)
    -> FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES department (DEPTNO));
```

and here is the error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES department (DEPTNO))' at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a comma (`,`) between primary key and foreign key definition:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EMPNO INT(4) NOT NULL,
  ENAME CHAR(10),
  MGR CHAR(9),
  DEPTNO INT(4) NOT NULL,
  SAL FLOAT(7, 2),
  JOB_STATUS FLOAT(7, 2),
  PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO), -- here
  FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES department (DEPTNO)
);
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) of `CREATE TABLE` syntax, definitions (e.g. columns, primary key, foreign keys) must be separated with `,`:

> ```
> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
> [(create_definition,...)]
> ```